# Creating a structure using an aggregation query that groups by multiple ids

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have a collection named `Vote` that looks like the following:

```
{
  postId: "1",
  comment:{ 
    text_sentiment: "positive",
    topic: "A"
  }
}, // DOC-1

{
  postId: "2",
  comment:{ 
     text_sentiment: "negative",
     topic: "A"
  }
}, // DOC-2

{
  postId: "3",
  comment:{ 
     text_sentiment: "positive",
     topic: "B"
  }
},..//DOC-3 ..
```

I want to do an aggregation on this collection such that it returns the following structure.

```
[
   {
      _id: "hash",
      topic: "A",
      topicOccurance: 2,
      sentiment: {
        positive: 1,
        negative: 1,
        neutral: 0
      },
      postIds: [1,2]
   },
   ..
]
```

I created the following aggregation:

```
db.Vote.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            surveyId: "e6d38e1ecd",
            "comment.topic": {
                $exists: 1
            },

        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                topic: "$comment.topic",
                text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"
            },
            total: {
                $sum: 1
            },

        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.topic",
            total: {
                $sum: "$total"
            },
            text_sentiments: {
                $push: {
                    k: "$_id.text_sentiment",
                    v: "$total"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            topic: "$_id",
            topicOccurance: "$total",
            sentiment: {
                "$arrayToObject": "$text_sentiments"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "topicOccurance": -1
        }
    }
])
```

This works fine but I do not know how can I also get an array in the response holding the key `postIds`. Each document inside the collection vote has `postId` and I want to group the posts having the same topic and push to an array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd stage (`$group`) - Add `postId` into `postIds` array via `$push`.

3rd stage (`$group`) - Add `postIds` array into `postIds` array via `$push`. This will leads `postIds` become nested array.

```
[[1,2], ...]
```

4th stage (`$project`) - For `postIds` field, use `$reduce` operator to flatten the `postIds` array by `$concat`. **Update: with `$setUnion` to distinct items in array.**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // match stage
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        topic: "$comment.topic",
        text_sentiment: "$comment.text_sentiment"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      postIds: {
        $push: "$postId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.topic",
      total: {
        $sum: "$total"
      },
      text_sentiments: {
        $push: {
          k: "$_id.text_sentiment",
          v: "$total"
        }
      },
      postIds: {
        "$push": "$postIds"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      topic: "$_id",
      topicOccurance: "$total",
      sentiment: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$text_sentiments"
      },
      postIds: {
        $setUnion: [
          {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$postIds",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // sort stage
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hxlq21idB43)

Comment: Thank you. What does `$$value` and `$$this` mean? Could you please explain?

Comment: Hi `$$value` is refer to variable from initialValue, while `$$this` is refer to current iterate item in the `input` array.

Comment: Is there some documentation for this?

Comment: Here `postIds` also has duplicates. How to avoid duplicates?

Comment: For the dos, I don't think there are MongoDB docs that explain both variables, but it does provide the sample on how to use it. [`$reduce`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/)

Comment: You can use `$setUnion` to distinct the item in array.